# Magento admin grid edit form display on left side

Tags: admin, adminhtml, adminform, grid, admin-panel

Hi i am not so familer with magento , so i am getting some problem in magento admin grid
problem is admin grid edit form is displaying on left side with tabs like in image below
Thanks in advance for help
[image]

my code is here
Ooorza/PaypalAdaptivePayment/controllers/AdminhtmlTransactionController.php

```
<?php

class Ooorza_PaypalAdaptivePayment_Adminhtml_TransactionController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{

    protected function _initAction() {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('adaptivepayment');
            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypaladaptivepayment/adminhtml_transaction'));
            //->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));

        return $this;
    }   

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_initAction()
            ->renderLayout();
    }

    public function editAction() {
        $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model  = Mage::getModel('paypaladaptivepayment/paytransaction')->load($id);

        if ($model->getId() || $id == 0) {
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $model->setData($data);
            }

            Mage::register('adaptivetransaction_data', $model);

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('adaptivepayment');

            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypaladaptivepayment/adminhtml_transaction_edit'))
                ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypaladaptivepayment/adminhtml_transaction_edit_tabs'));

            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('paypaladaptivepayment')->__('Item does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

    public function newAction() {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function saveAction() {
        echo "string";
    }

    public function deleteAction() {

    }

    public function massDeleteAction() {

    }

    public function massStatusAction()
    {

    }

    public function exportCsvAction()
    {
        $fileName   = 'adaptivetransaction.csv';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypaladaptivepayment/adminhtml_transactions
            _grid')
            ->getCsv();

        $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }

    public function exportXmlAction()
    {
        $fileName   = 'adaptivetransaction.xml';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypaladaptivepayment/adminhtml_transaction_grid')
            ->getXml();

        $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }

    protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream')
    {
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1 200 OK','');
        $response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true);
        $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);
        $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$fileName);
        $response->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'));
        $response->setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
        $response->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content));
        $response->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType);
        $response->setBody($content);
        $response->sendResponse();
        die;
    }
}
```

Ooorza/PaypalAdaptivePayment/Block/Adminhtml/Transaction.php

```
<?php
class Ooorza_PaypalAdaptivePayment_Block_Adminhtml_Transaction extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_transaction';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'paypaladaptivepayment';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('paypaladaptivepayment')->__('Item Manager');
    $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('paypaladaptivepayment')->__('Add Item');
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

Ooorza/PaypalAdaptivePayment/Block/Adminhtml/Transaction/Grid.php

```
<?php

class Ooorza_PaypalAdaptivePayment_Block_Adminhtml_Transaction_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->setId('adaptivepaymentGrid');
      $this->setDefaultSort('adaptivepayment_id');
      $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
      $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
  }

  protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
      $collection = Mage::getModel('paypaladaptivepayment/paytransaction')->getCollection();
      $this->setCollection($collection);
      return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }

  protected function _prepareColumns()
  {
      $this->addColumn('pay_id',
             array(
                    'header' => 'ID',
                    'align' =>'right',
                    'width' => '50px',
                    'index' => 'pay_id',
               ));
       $this->addColumn('order_id',
               array(
                    'header' => 'Order ID',
                    'align' =>'left',
                    'index' => 'order_id',
              ));
       $this->addColumn('transaction_id', array(
                    'header' => 'transaction id',
                    'align' =>'left',
                    'index' => 'transaction_id',
             ));
        $this->addColumn('paykey', array(
                     'header' => 'paykey',
                     'align' =>'left',
                     'index' => 'paykey',
          ));

        $this->addColumn('transaction_status', array(
                     'header' => 'transaction_status',
                     'align' =>'left',
                     'index' => 'transaction_status',
          ));

        $this->addColumn('currency', array(
                     'header' => 'currency',
                     'align' =>'left',
                     'index' => 'currency',
          ));

        $this->addColumn('amount', array(
                     'header' => 'amount',
                     'align' =>'left',
                     'index' => 'amount',
          ));

        $this->addColumn('vendor_mail', array(
                     'header' => 'vendor_mail',
                     'align' =>'left',
                     'index' => 'vendor_mail',
          ));

        $this->addColumn('sender_mail', array(
                     'header' => 'sender_mail',
                     'align' =>'left',
                     'index' => 'sender_mail',
          ));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('paypaladaptivepayment')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('paypaladaptivepayment')->__('XML'));

      return parent::_prepareColumns();
  }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('custom_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('custom');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
             'label'    => Mage::helper('custom')->__('Delete'),
             'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
             'confirm'  => Mage::helper('custom')->__('Are you sure?')
        ));

        $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('custom/status')->getOptionArray();

        array_unshift($statuses, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('custom')->__('Change status'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array('_current'=>true)),
             'additional' => array(
                    'visibility' => array(
                         'name' => 'status',
                         'type' => 'select',
                         'class' => 'required-entry',
                         'label' => Mage::helper('custom')->__('Status'),
                         'values' => $statuses
                     )
             )
        ));
        return $this;
    }

  public function getRowUrl($row)
  {
      return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
  }

}
```

Ooorza/PaypalAdaptivePayment/Block/Adminhtml/Transaction/Edit.php

```
<?php

class Ooorza_PaypalAdaptivePayment_Block_Adminhtml_Transaction_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'custom';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_custom';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('custom')->__('Save Item'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('custom')->__('Delete Item'));

        $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
            'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
            'class'     => 'save',
        ), -100);


    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if( Mage::registry('custom_data') && Mage::registry('custom_data')->getId() ) {
            return Mage::helper('custom')->__("Edit Item '%s'", $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('custom_data')->getTitle()));
        } else {
            return Mage::helper('custom')->__('Add Item');
        }
    }
}
```

Ooorza/PaypalAdaptivePayment/Block/Adminhtml/Transaction/Edit/Tabs.php

```
<?php

class Ooorza_PaypalAdaptivePayment_Block_Adminhtml_Transaction_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{

  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->setId('adaptivetransaction_tabs');
      $this->setDestElementId('adaptivetransaction_edit_form');
      $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('paypaladaptivepayment')->__('Item Information'));
  }

  protected function _beforeToHtml()
  {
      $this->addTab('form_section', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('paypaladaptivepayment')->__('Item Information'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('paypaladaptivepayment')->__('Item'),
          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypaladaptivepayment/adminhtml_transaction_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
      ));

      return parent::_beforeToHtml();
  }
}
```

Ooorza/PaypalAdaptivePayment/Block/Adminhtml/Transaction/Edit/Form.php

```
<?php

class Ooorza_PaypalAdaptivePayment_Block_Adminhtml_Transaction_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
  protected function _prepareForm()
  {
      $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                      'id' => 'edit_form',
                                      'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                                      'method' => 'post',
                                      'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                                   )
      );

      $form->setUseContainer(true);
      $this->setForm($form);
      return parent::_prepareForm();
  }
}
```

Ooorza/PaypalAdaptivePayment/Block/Adminhtml/Transaction/Edit/tab/Form.php

```
<?php

class Ooorza_PaypalAdaptivePayment_Block_Adminhtml_Transaction_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
  protected function _prepareForm()
  {
      $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
      $this->setForm($form);
      $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('adaptivetransaction_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('paypaladaptivepayment')->__('Item information')));

      $fieldset->addField('order_id', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('paypaladaptivepayment')->__('Oder ID'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'order_id',
      ));

      $fieldset->addField('transaction_id', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('paypaladaptivepayment')->__('Transaction ID'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'transaction_id',
      ));

      if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getCustomData() )
      {
          $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getAdaptivetransactionData());
          Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setAdaptivetransactionData(null);
      } elseif ( Mage::registry('adaptivetransaction_data') ) {
          $form->setValues(Mage::registry('adaptivetransaction_data')->getData());
      }
      return parent::_prepareForm();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

In the class `Ooorza_PaypalAdaptivePayment_Block_Adminhtml_Transaction_Edit_Tabs` replace this line

```
$this->setDestElementId('adaptivetransaction_edit_form');
```

with

```
$this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
```